# How to include filename when importing txt / csv file in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, csv

When I import a csv-file in postgres using psql I would like to add the filename in a column (before each row). Is this possible?

The command I am using:

```
psql.exe -h host-U user -d database -c "\COPY schema.table FROM filename.csv with csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize you stated "before each row" but you probably need to modify the .CSV contents in the language of your choice to do that.

Otherwise you could send a followup psql command after your first command to create the new column and update it with the filename:

```
psql.exe -h host-U user -d database -c "ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD COLUMN filename character varying(255);UPDATE schema.table SET filename='filename.csv' WHERE filename IS NULL;"
```